# Dynamic field validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I have a form built with my own form builder, my form builder is similar to Gravity form for WordPress. Everything is working fine except the validation. Every time I submit the form it returns true.

Especially, I'm validating the `select` field, because the user can edit the value from web inspector and submit the value, that's why I'm checking the value against saved values in DB where the dynamic form is saved.
Here is my try

`where $post is $_POST[] array, $postKey is fieldName, & $postValue is submitted value by user`.

```
public function validate()
{
    $post = $this->ci->input->post();
    //check form tempering
    if(empty($post)) 
        return false;

    $formId = $post['form_id'];
    //get form from db
    $data=[];
    $this->ci->db->select('formData');
    $this->ci->db->where('formId', $formId);
    $query = $this->ci->db->get(TBL_FORM_DATA);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->row();
    }
    if(empty($data) ) 
        return false;
    //unset submit button and 0 if occurs

    unset($post['submit']);
    unset($post['0']);

    //decode json
    $data = json_decode($data->formData,true);
    $fields = $data['field'];
    //debug($fields);
    //iterate post values and keys

    foreach ($post as $postKey => $postValue) 
    {
        //echo '<br>'.$postKey;
        if(strpos($postKey, '@'))
        {
            list($fieldName,$field_id) = explode('@', $postKey);

            $field_display_name = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $fieldName));

            if(strpos($field_id,'|')) {
                list($field_id,$price) = explode('|', $field_id);
            }

            $field = $fields[$field_id];
            //debug($field['choice'],false);

            if(isset($field['choice']) && (isset($field['choice']['label']) && isset($field['choice']['value'])) )
            {
                /*if(!in_array($postValue, $field['choice']['value'])) 
                {*/
                    //$list = implode(',', $field['choice']['value']);

                    $this->ci->form_validation->set_rules($postKey,$field_display_name,'callback_check_field['.$list.']');
                    /*$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules($postKey, $field_display_name,"in_list[".$list."]",
                        array('in_list' => 'Invalid Selection. Please Select from available choices.')
                    );*/
                /*}*/
            }

            if(isset($field['required']) && $field['required']=='on'){
                $this->ci->form_validation->set_rules($postKey, $field_display_name,'required|trim');
            }

            //$duplicate = isset($field['no_duplicate']) ? true : false;
            //$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules('form_id',' ','required');
            //$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules('inkform_total',' ','required');    
        }
        $this->ci->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="clearfix"></div><p class="alert alert-danger">','</p>');

        return $this->ci->form_validation->run();

    }


    //echo validation_errors();

}
```

The callback function to check the select field values

```
function check_field($field,$list)
{ 
    if(!is_array($list)) {
        $list = explode(',', $list);
    }
    if(!in_array($field, $list)){
        $this->ci->form_validation->set_message('check_field','Invalid Post');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

And later i just want to access `validate()` function for validating.

Comment: what exactly "isn't working"... everything? or just your select validation?

Comment: @Alex, Only the validation is not working, for all fields not just for select. Its returning True on every submit

Comment: mkay, and just to be sure, you are intentionally trying to make it fail correct e.g. not entering valid data? futher I don't see any blairing mistakes with your code but it isn't very easy to troubleshoot with the bit of info provided. please read up one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. essentially generate an example we can easily run on our systems to troubleshoot (complete/verifiable). remove the unnecessary bits so it is *minimal*.

Comment: i just share full code. please check once again.

Comment: @Alex, your answer helped, but not fully now i got `Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name What Do You Want ?.(check_field)`.
returned bu call back function.

Comment: where is the `check_field()` function? in the same class as `validate()`?

Comment: the field name is  `What_do_you_want_?@5` where `@` is delimiter that i use to break this and get `5` which is input field id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171971/discussion-between-manoj-bist-and-alex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
$this->ci->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="clearfix"></div><p class="alert alert-danger">','</p>');
return $this->ci->form_validation->run();
```

**outside** the foreach